# Postgres dynamic limit offset in DO block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

The below query errors on `ERROR: column "page" does not exist`

If I replace (j) and (page) with hardcoded values; then the query will run.

My goal is to walk through `records_to_update` table; and then update a batch of records at a time.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
  page int := 50;
BEGIN
  FOR j IN 0..(select count(*) from records_to_update) BY page LOOP 
    
   with subset_to_update as (
    select
        * from records_to_update
    order by target_class_id, main_type_id, source_class_id 
    offset (j)
    limit (page)
    ) update large_table_to_update
    set to_update_class_id = stu.target_class_id
    from
        subset_to_update stu
    where
    large_table_to_update.annotation_class_id = stu.source_class_id;

     
    COMMIT;            
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Comment: See [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: Hmm, I set up a test case on my end with the idea of presenting an answer but I could not replicate the error. What version of Postgres are you using?